# There are some way to print error log to an external file using g++ C++ compiler? (C++)

Tags: c++, file, compiler-construction, g++, logging

i'm trying to compile my code with g++ C++ compiler on Windows and the compiler is returning some errors. Ok, as usual. But it's printing so much errors that the console just goes down to the end and I can't see the first lines of error log. My question is: there are any way to print the error log to an external file so I can read the complete error log?

i.e.

```
g++ *.h *.cpp > error_log.txt
```

Thanks!

Comment: g++ *.h *.cpp 2> error_log.txt

Comment: Besides, why would you want to compile header files?

Comment: You also might want to read about -fmax-errors

Comment: Generally prefer to use `tee` which will allow you see the log on the console as well as create a log file, say `g++ -Wall *.cpp 2>&1 | tee log`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to redirect `stderr`, but it is shell dependant.

For example on `sh` and `bash`, you can use:

```
g++ file 2> error.log
```

On `csh` and `tcsh` it would be:

```
( g++ file ) >& error.log
```

Answer (score 6):

```
g++ *.cpp > log_file.txt 2>&1
```

First the `>` allows us to redirect the standard output to the log file. Then by using the `2>&1` we redirect the error output to the standard output. By doing so, we redirect every output to the log_file.txt.

Comment: This is interesting, I didn't knew this was possible.

Answer (score 4):

```
g++ *.h *.cpp 2> error_log.txt
```

Notice the '2' It represents stderr.